# Django forms not showing error when empty

Tags: python, django, forms, input, show

I have Django forms, but they don't become red or show an error when they are empty (they are required). I am sort of sure of what to do.

views.py

```
def lOut(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        context = {
            "extendVar":"baseLoggedIn.html",
        }
    if request.user.is_authenticated()==False:
        form=registerForm(request.POST or None) 
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            print ("yup")
        elif form.is_valid()==False:
            print ("nup")
            print (form.errors)
        print("eh")     
        context= {
            "extendVar":"baseNotLoggedIn.html",
            "form":form,
        }
```

base.html:

```
{% extends extendVar %}

{% block title %}
    {{ block.super }} lagro
{% endblock %}

{% block fname %}
    {{ form.fname }}
{% endblock %}

{% block lname %}
    {{ form.lname }}
{% endblock %}

{% block email %}
    {{ form.email }}
{% endblock %}

{% block emailConfirm %}
    {{ form.emailConfirm }}
{% endblock %}

{% block password %}
    {{ form.password }}
{% endblock %}
```

baseNotLoggedIn.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'try3' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row row-buffer">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-right:5px;" >
        {% block fname %} {% endblock %}                
        <!-- <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="fname"> -->
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left:5px;">
        {% block lname %} {% endblock %}
        <!-- <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname"> -->
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row row-buffer">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group-lg">
        {% block email %} {% endblock %}
        <!-- <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email"> -->

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-buffer">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group-lg">
        {% block emailConfirm %} {% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-buffer">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group-lg">
        {% block password %} {% endblock %}                
        <!-- <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password"> -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-buffer">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group-lg">
        <button type = "submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="outline-width:0;">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

forms.py

```
class registerForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name',}))
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name',}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email',}))
    emailConfirm = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Confirm email',}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Password',}))
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't show up because you didn't render any errors in your template. Quoting from [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages):

> You need to make sure we take care of any errors for each field and
>   any errors for the form as a whole. Note {{ form.non_field_errors }}
>   at the top of the form and the template lookup for errors on each
>   field. Using {{ form.name_of_field.errors }} displays a list of form
>   errors.

Read [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) to learn how to render form errors in template.

Answer (score 0):

Change your forms.py to this.

```
class registerForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name','required': True}))
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name','required': True}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email','required': True}))
    emailConfirm = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Confirm email','required': True}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Password','required': True}))
```

P.S. Add 'required': True to your attrs dict.

See this.

```
>>> name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': True})
>>> name.render('name', 'A name')
'<input name="name" type="text" value="A name" required />'
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: oh ok thanks so much! now it works. just a quick question: for forms, do you use a third party like registration redux or do u just make your own forms?

Comment: I prefer my own forms.